# Connect two android devices via USB

Tags: android, usb, host, accessory

I'm trying to figure out how to connect two Android powered devices,
namely a smartphone (Android 4.1.2) and an android developer 
board (Android 4.0.4) with apps running on each, via USB and get them 
to communicate with each other.
Right now the developer board is running as the host and the phone as
an accessory. The hosts app is searching for connected devices and is
able to identify the phone as a device, but the app running on the
phone isn't able to find the host.
I've searched the web for quite a while now (!!) but I didn't come 
up with anything helpful yet that solved my problem.
For my project it is crucial that I use an USB connection, so please
don't propose that I use bluetooth, WiFi, or anything else...
Regards

Answer (score 4):

USB is host initiated, so it's not surprising that this is not working. Your device that is functioning as the USB device should respond to requests initiated from the USB host. You will probably have to create some sort of vendor specific protocol around this. I don't know what you are trying to do with this connection, but if the device needs to know things on the host you will need to bake this in to your protocol definition and send that information directly to the device.

What you could try doing is using both devices as a host and connecting a USB to UART bridge device between them, then you can transmit data generically in any direction by using the serial connection (through [`USBManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html) if the USB protocol is available, or some [Android Java Serial class](https://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/source/browse/trunk/project/src/android/serialport/SerialPort.java?r=8) if it is not), plus you don't have to worry about the host-device connection. This would look something like this:

`[Android 4.1.2 Device]<--USB Connection-->[USB to UART Bridge]<--Serial Connection-->[USB to UART Bridge]<--USB Connection-->[Android 4.0.4 Device]`.

Answer (score -2):

Use **OTG** **Cable** to interact with your board and phone. Its easily available in the market.

Comment: sorry, but your answer is not helpful.

Comment: It actually is.... Allputer has a nice OTG cable where you can connect 2 Android devices. If you use proper Android OS, then the one device should assign itself as the host and the other as the accessory, without having to do anything... The AOA standard applies here.
http://allputer.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=240_217&products_id=2282

Comment: This does not address the question asked, as the question makes it quite clear that a USB connection between the devices has *already* been achieved.  It's also quite possible that the "Android Developer Board" has a full size USB "A" host connector, making an OTG adapter cable unnecessary.